# I need help with adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I do not have a clear understanding about adjectives and am having trouble identifying the adjective in the following sentence:

> Sally doesn't have a sign.

Comment: There is no adjective in _Sally doesn't have a sign_. Unless your textbook thinks the indefinite article _**a**_ is an adjective. Which would be unfortunate, because _a_ is not an adjective. In the sentence _Sally doesn't have a big sign_ there **is** an adjective, but not in the one you gave.

Comment: @JohnLawler What kind of weird textbooks say articles are adjectives? Is that a thing?

Comment: Articles modify nouns, and to some teachers, that's the definition of an adjective. You have no idea how many stupid ideas there are floating around labelled as "English grammar".

Answer (score 1):

That's because the sentence in question doesn't have an adjective!

Here's a version with an adjective:

> Sally doesn't have a big sign.

*Big* is an adjective that describes *sign*.